# Components from Links in Home.js not rendering correctly with sub Component Header were HeaderToolbar is rendered

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, routes, rendering

The main issue in these app is that there are Components in HeaderToolbar were each component has a link with its adequate Route. HeaderToolbar is render inside Header with is rendered inside Home.js. The links are shown in the /home page but once each link clicked the webpage redirects to a whole new page but the elements of the specific component is not shown. When inspected it shows that it seems to be a whole different page that has been rendered from clicking each link of each Component in "/home". I am hacking a React.js template so there are some patterns and techniques I still don't know. Any help would be appreciated.

Home Component Rendered:

```
export default function Home() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
   
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Header title="Colectivo Simbiosis"/>     
        <main>
          <MainFeaturedPost post={mainFeaturedPost} />
          <Grid container spacing={5}>
            {featuredPosts.map((post) => (
              <FeaturedPost key={post.title} post={post} />
            ))}
          </Grid>
          <Grid container spacing={5} className={classes.mainGrid}>
            <Sidebar
              title={sidebar.title}
              description={sidebar.description}
              archives={sidebar.archives}
              social={sidebar.social}
            />
          </Grid>
        </main>
      </Container>
      <Footer title="Footer" description="Something here to give the footer a purpose!" />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Header Component:

```
export default function Header(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { sections, title } = props;

  return (
  
    <React.Fragment>
      <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
        <Button size="small">Subscribe</Button>
        <Typography
          component="h2"
          variant="h5"
          color="inherit"
          align="center"
          noWrap
          className={classes.toolbarTitle}>
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <IconButton>
          <SearchIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Button variant="outlined" size="small">
          Sign up
        </Button>
      </Toolbar>
      <HeaderToolbar></HeaderToolbar>   
      
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

HeaderToolbar Component:

```
const HeaderToolbar = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();


    return (
      <div>
      <Toolbar component="nav" variant="dense" className={classes.toolbarSecondary}>
        <Link to='/quienessomos'>  Quienes Somos  </Link>
        <Link to='/compositores'>  Compositores  </Link>
        <Link to='/blog'>  Blog  </Link>
        <Link to='/forum'>  Forum  </Link>
      </Toolbar>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/quienessomos' component={QuienesSomos}/>
        <Route exact path='/compositores' component={Composers}/>
        <Route exact path='/composer1'  component={Composer1}/>
        <Route exact path='/composer2' component={Composer2}/>
        <Route exact path='/blog' component={Blog2}/>
        <Route exact path='/forum' component= {ForumContainer}/>
      </Switch>   
        
      </div>
        

    )
  }

export default HeaderToolbar
```

Comment: It isn't quite clear what your issue is, perhaps you've not included all the relevant code. What/where is your "/home" route/page? Where is your `Router` component that should be wrapping all the `Link` and `Route` components. I also see no `Redirect` components nor imperative redirects. Can you clarify what your observations are? What is the "it" you inspected? I suspect you've accidentally nested the routes in `HeaderToolbar` if you've another level of routes, one of which is rendering *some* "/home" path which renders `Home` and subsequently the toolbar.

Comment: Your suggestions were very accurate. I implemented a Router to wrap the Links and Routes and indeed they are nested. How do I unnest them. Should I code them in the Home.js page.? Thank you very much!

Comment: Drew I was wondering. How do I unnest the sub components so that they don't end up nested under "/home"?

Comment: You could move those route declarations out to the root level. That or don't render `HeaderToolbar` via the home page component which is only rendered on the single "/home" path. Can you update your question to include your root app component with the `Router`? Can you also indicate when you want the toolbar to actually render?